# Android Firebase - Display data in RecyclerView Adapter inside Fragment

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-arrayadapter

This is my database.

```
`{
  "users" : {
    "post" : {
      "3kcjEiWdeic2HLuWk7WooVpyXHQ2" : {
        "19:19:13 2019-02-23" : {
          "description" : "some description",
          "photoUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/revoney-c5ada.appspot.com/o/3kcjEiWdeic2HLuWk7WooVpyXHQ2%2FImages%2FImg20190223_191905.jpg?alt=media&token=4e3c81b7-4df0-4c04-aa2d-5554ceecf1c2",
          "title" : "some title"
        },
        "19:27:23 2019-02-23" : {
          "description" : "jhhghjjnn",
          "photoUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/revoney-c5ada.appspot.com/o/3kcjEiWdeic2HLuWk7WooVpyXHQ2%2FImages%2FImg20190223_192702.jpg?alt=media&token=09c3ce5a-9b9f-4168-823c-f816fc99d7fd",
          "title" : "ygggyujj"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}`
```

This is my adapter class where I inflate the views to show the photos and the information.

```
    public class RecyclerHomeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerHomeAdapter.ItemDataViewHolder>{

    List<HomeObject> data;

    public RecyclerHomeAdapter(List<HomeObject> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ItemDataViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.home_row, parent, false);
        ItemDataViewHolder holder = new ItemDataViewHolder(view);

             return holder;

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ItemDataViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        final HomeObject homeObject = data.get(position);

        holder.usernameHomeTextView.setText(homeObject.getNameUser());
        holder.descriptionHomeTextview.setText(homeObject.getDescription());
        holder.commentsHomeTextview.setText(homeObject.getComments());
        holder.likesHomeTextView.setText(homeObject.getLikes());


        Picasso.get().load(homeObject.getPhotoProfile()).fit().centerCrop()
                .rotate(270).noFade().into(holder.profilePhotoHomeImageView);

        Picasso.get().load(homeObject.getPhotoUrl()).fit().centerCrop()
                .rotate(270).noFade().into(holder.postPhotoImageView);

        Picasso.get().load(homeObject.getPhotoProfile()).fit().centerCrop()
                .rotate(270).noFade().into(holder.descriptionPhotoHomeImageView);



    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }


    public class ItemDataViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    ImageView profilePhotoHomeImageView, postPhotoImageView, likesHomeImageView,commentsHomeImageView;
    ImageView  followHomeImageView, helpHomeImageView, descriptionPhotoHomeImageView;
    TextView usernameHomeTextView,descriptionHomeTextview,commentsHomeTextview,likesHomeTextView;
    Button purchasseHomeButton;

    public ItemDataViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        profilePhotoHomeImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profilePhotoHomeImageView);
        postPhotoImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.postPhotoImageView);
        likesHomeImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.likesHomeImageView);
        commentsHomeImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.commentsHomeImageView);
        followHomeImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.followHomeImageView);
        helpHomeImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.helpHomeImageView);
        descriptionPhotoHomeImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.descriptionPhotoHomeImageView);
        usernameHomeTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.usernameHomeTextView);
        descriptionPhotoHomeImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.descriptionPhotoHomeImageView);
        descriptionHomeTextview = itemView.findViewById(R.id.descriptionHomeTextview);
        commentsHomeTextview = itemView.findViewById(R.id.commentsHomeTextview);
        purchasseHomeButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.purchasseHomeButton);
        likesHomeTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.likesHomeTextView);
    }
}
    }
```

This is the fragment where I want to display the posts.

```
    public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    // Write a message to the database
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference mRef;
    StorageReference storageRef;
    FirebaseStorage storage;
    FirebaseAuth auth;
    RecyclerView rv;
    List<HomeObject> data;
    RecyclerHomeAdapter adapter;
    HomeObject homeObject;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        rv = view.findViewById(R.id.home_recycler);

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        storageRef = storage.getReference();

        //RETRIEVE IMAGES
        homeObject = new HomeObject();

        rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        data = new ArrayList<>();

        adapter = new RecyclerHomeAdapter(data);
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("Users/Post");

        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                data.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    HomeObject post = postSnapshot.getValue(HomeObject.class);
                    data.add(post);
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

I've tried to display the posts but without any fortune. I'm trying to recover firebase data and display it in a recyclerview adapter inside fragment. Can someone help me?

Comment: Please add your database structure.

Answer (score 0):

You should use another for loop inside the for loop of your code and it should check postSnapshot.getChildren() so that you can retrieve the data below the date field.